# Expand input on click in search icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I´m trying to do something like when I click in my search icon the input expands with nice effect. I found a tutorial here explain what I was trying to do. I follow the tutorial but in my example is not working, I guess I did everything correct. Anyone there already tried to do this? Can give a help?
The only difference that I have from the example is that I have the input inside my menu like this:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contacts.php">Contacts</a></li> 
        <li style="float:right; list-style:none"</li>
            <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
                <form>
                    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
                    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                    <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</nav>
```

**The link for tutorial:** http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/

**What I´m getting:** http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/knprc/2/

Comment: Please reduce your demo to the *minimal* amount of code that demonstrates your problem; we don't need the mass of mobile platform detection: we only need the bit relevant your search box's expansion/contraction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its just because this javascript of the example is complex and I´m not an expert on javascript and I dont want to take off someting important.

Comment: I update now my jsfiddle based on the documentation of this example.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
<li style="float:right; list-style:none"</li>
```

should read:

```
<li style="float:right; list-style:none">
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your attention! But that isn´t the problem of the expand effect on click is not working!